# IntelliJ idea - switch between all open editors (functionality similar to Ctrl+e)

Tags: intellij-idea

I need Idea to show me all opened editors. With possibility to switch into editor by matching keyboard input. Just alternative to Ctrl+E/Ctrl+Shift+E, but showing absolutely all the files opened.

And I know about Switcher (Ctrl+tab), so that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: All files that are displayed as tabs on top of editor windows.

Comment: You are not looking for Switcher, OK. But what else you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have defined it so `Ctrl+Page_Up / Ctrl+Page_Down` Switches between all opened tabs (just like in chrome and many other applications)

You can define it yourself at -
Settings -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Window -> Select next tab / select previous tab

Comment: Oops.. I think it's not defined by default.. Settings -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Window -> Select next tab / select previous tab.

Comment: Beware, Ctrl+Page_Up / Ctrl+Page_Down has already a useful assigned action.

Answer (score 6):

Try `Ctrl+Tab` and hold down the `Ctrl` key. It opens up the switcher. You can navigate between the tabs with arrow keys (`Tab` key itself also works). Release the `Ctrl` key when done.